# Can real continuous functions extend to complex continuous, or at least continuous with with countable poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

In most cases, real analytic functions can be extended to complex analytic functions. Can something similar happen for only continuous functions? There are obviously some cases where a function would be analogous to meromorphic in the cases, but I would expect some kind of extension to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any continuous real function from a closed subset of a metric space can be extended to a continuous function on the whole space by Tietze Extension Theorem. Since the real line is closed in the complex plane a continuous extension is always possible.

Comment: How is the real line closed? Isn't $(-\infty, \infty)$ open? If Open sets are now suddenly closed sets I need to yell at my topology teacher.

Comment: $(-\infty, \infty)$ is open in the real line, not in the complex plane. If a sequence of real numbers converges to a complex number isn't it true that the limit is actually a real number?  @RandomWordMashup

Comment: So when you say closed, do you mean in the abstract algebra sense or the topological sense?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup Topologically - but remember that some sets are both open and closed, and that the ambient space matters: $\mathbb{R}$ is both closed and open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and is closed but not open as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Continuity is **much easier** to satisfy than analyticity: if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then so are each of the following functions $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ extending $f$:

$$a+bi\mapsto f(a)+f(b)i,\quad a+bi\mapsto f(a)+0i, \quad a+bi\mapsto f(a)+17\sin(b^2-46a)i.$$ The point is that unlike analyticity, continuity doesn't impose much restraint on how the real and imaginary parts of a function need to interact.

---

In fact, the above situation generalizes quite strongly: if $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to *any* [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) $X$, then the function $$\hat{f}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow X: a+bi\mapsto f(a)$$ extends $f$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and is still continuous. All we're doing here is "precomposing" $f$ with the continuous projection function $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:a+bi\mapsto a$.

Comment: How does this explain a function like $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ which is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ but has poles in the complex plane?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup There are multiple ways one might try to extend a function. What I've shown above is that there will be **some** way to extend $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto {1\over x^2+1}$$ to a continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$, not that "the natural" idea will work.

Comment: Under what circumstances then may one replace $x$ for a continuous function $f(x)$ with $z$ and say that it is an extension to a continuous complex function?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup That's not well-defined in general. For example, consider the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $C$; what should "$C(3+2i)$" mean? Some functions (e.g. rational functions, trig functions, etc.) come with natural "candidate extensions" and then your question makes sense, but in general it's not clear what that should mean. *(Note that those candidate extensions generally come from the Taylor series ...)*

Comment: Consider a Weierstrass function.

Comment: @RandomWordMashup OK, what about a Weierstrass function? Are you asking if it can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$? If so, the answer is **yes**, and I've said how to do that in my answer (if no, what are you asking about it?).

Comment: So it can be extended to "a" function, but in practice that statement alone has very little significance. What can you say about the actual structure of that extension? What are the real or imaginary components?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup At this point I'm not sure what you're asking. I've written down explicit ways to extend continuous functions, so you can read off the real and imaginary components directly; everything was completely explicit. I don't know what more "actual structure" is desired.

Comment: I have no idea where you pulled that random trig function from. If you're saying an extension encompasses a family of functions, it would be helpful to specify as such.